# Convert nested tags to html based on ID attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the sample XML for the problem :

```
<functions>
  <function id="678">
            <name>getFunctions()</name>
            <File ID="1">
                <ncss>0</ncss>
                <ccn>0</ccn>
                <javadocs>0</javadocs>
            </File>
            <File ID="2">
                <ncss>5</ncss>
                <ccn>3</ccn>
                <javadocs>1</javadocs>
            </File>

           <function>    
        </functions>
```

I need the output to be in the following format (table)

```
FunctionId  Name            FileID    NCSS  CCN   Javadocs
678         getFunctions()  1         0      0      0
                            2         5      3      1
```

The problem with this is that I am able to get the desired output when I substitute the 2 File tags with other texts  ( e.g  sourceFile and destFile instead of File id="1" and File id="2").

But I need it to be in the above format and I have no clue how to go about it .
All inputs will be appreciated.

Thank You.

This is the XSLT snippet I used before this :

```
<center><h1>Function Summary</h1></center>

<table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="5">

 <tr>
    <th width="73" align="center" valign="top">ID</th>
    <th width="176" align="center" valign="top">Name></th>
    <th colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">File</th>
    <th colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">NCSS</th>
    <th colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">CCN</th>
    <th colspan="2" align="center" valign="top">Javadocs</th>
  </tr>


  <xsl:for-each select="//function">

  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">  <xsl:value-of select="@id" />  </td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">  <xsl:value-of select="name" /> </td>

    <td width="40" align="center" valign="top">srcFile</td>

    <td width="50" align="center" valign="top">summaryFile</td>

    <td width="63" align="center" valign="top"> <xsl:value-of select="sourceFile/ncss" /> </td>
    <td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="summaryFile/ncss" /></td>
    <td width="53" align="center" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="sourceFile/ccn" /></td>
    <td width="66" align="center" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="summaryFile/ccn" /></td>
    <td width="108" align="center" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="sourceFile/javadocs" /></td>
    <td width="109" align="center" valign="top"><xsl:value-of select="summaryFile/javadocs" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

sourceFile and summaryFile had been replaced with File id="1" and File id="2" respectively.
The output would be an HTML table only.

Comment: can you post the xslt that you already have ?

Comment: are you looking for text format output ?

Comment: @LaxmikanthSamudrala Edited question to include relevant XSLT snippet above.

I am looking for an XSLT 1.0 based solution.

Answer (score 1):

this outputs you in text format

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="functions/function"
            group-by="@id">

            <xsl:variable name="functionId" select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:variable name="functionName" select="name" />
            <xsl:for-each select="File">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        6 fields ...
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        4 fields
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your like to generate a table for each File where belonging to a function, where only the firs file has the functionName and  @id.

Many change would be to make your for-each run over files but only within the current function. Thant test if the current file is the first one (position() = 1) and add the name and @id.

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="functions">
    <center>
        <h1>Function Summary</h1>
    </center>

    <table width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="5">

        <tr>
            <th width="73" align="center" valign="top">ID</th>
            <th width="176" align="center" valign="top">Name</th>
            <th align="center" valign="top">File</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">NCSS</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">CCN</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">Javadocs</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="function"/>

    </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="function">

        <xsl:for-each select="//File">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="../@id" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="../name" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ncss" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ccn" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="javadocs" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<center xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <h1>Function Summary</h1>
</center><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="1000" border="1" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <th width="73" align="center" valign="top">ID</th>
    <th width="176" align="center" valign="top">Name</th>
    <th align="center" valign="top">File</th>
    <th align="center" valign="top">NCSS</th>
    <th align="center" valign="top">CCN</th>
    <th align="center" valign="top">Javadocs</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">678</td>
    <td align="left" valign="middle">getFunctions()</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">1</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"/>
    <td align="left" valign="middle"/>
    <td align="center" valign="top">2</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">5</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">3</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top">1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update:
To  **show empty cells** in table there are some possible solutions:

Add `&nbsp;` tom empty cells.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>
```

Usse css to show empty cells general

```
<style type="text/css">
    table { empty-cells: show; }
</style>
```

Update use rowspan to connect the rows in the first tow columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="functions">
    <center>
        <h1>Function Summary</h1>
    </center>
        <style type="text/css">
            table { empty-cells: show; }
        </style>
    <table  border="1" cellspacing="5">

        <tr>
            <th width="73" align="center" valign="top">ID</th>
            <th width="176" align="center" valign="top">Name</th>
            <th align="center" valign="top">File</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">NCSS</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">CCN</th>
            <th  align="center" valign="top">Javadocs</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="function"/>

    </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="function">
        <xsl:variable name="file_cnt" select="count(File)" />

        <xsl:for-each select="File">
            <tr>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1" >
                    <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="{$file_cnt}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../@id" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" rowspan="{$file_cnt}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../name" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:if>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@ID" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ncss" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ccn" />
                </td>
                <td  align="center" valign="top">
                    <xsl:value-of select="javadocs" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The document renders inappropriately( in IE & Firefox) after applying the given stylesheet

Comment: Oh: Sorry I did not have looked properly to the generated html. I'm also not entirely sure how the output should look like. But firs of all get rid of the `colspan` and for an first try remove also the width. Also there is still a javadocs td entry in my xslt

Comment: The problem still remains. As far as how the output should look , take a look at the text directly below the sample xml provided.

Comment: This more an html problem. But here fire-fox does not like empty td tags. Therefore add an `&nbsp` to the empty td tags. Put `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[&nbsp;]]></xsl:text>`just behind the `</if>`

Comment: @Aditya: Have a look to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h4QY2/) isn't this what your asking for?

Comment: First off , I'd like to apologize for the fact that I am unable to tag your name in this post , despite the required actions being performed , thereby disallowing the response to get to you on time.

This is exactly what I needed , alongwith the fact that there's only 1 row for name & id instead of 2.

Comment: @Aditya: Seems you like to use rowspan. Have a look to the update